# Convert a table into a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, aggregate, tabular

I have a data frame with three variables: a grouping variable (Group) and categorical variables indicating if the group is new (New) and if its entry is delinquent (Delinquent).

Here are **sample data**:

```
df <- structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), class = "factor"), New = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), Delinquent = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), .Names = c("Group", "New", "Delinquent"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
#df
```

I'm trying to count the number of delinquent groups, by whether they're new or not. To do this, I've wrapped `table` around `aggregate` on a simple data frame:

`yo <- table(aggregate(Delinquent ~ Group + New, data = df, FUN = max))`

which produces the rather odd output, an object of class "table"

```
yo
#, , Delinquent = 0
#
#     New
#Group FALSE TRUE
#    A     0    0
#    B     0    0
#    C     1    0
#    D     0    1
#    E     1    0
#    F     0    1
#    G     0    0
#
#, , Delinquent = 1
#
#     New
#Group FALSE TRUE
#    A     1    0
#    B     0    1
#    C     0    0
#    D     0    0
#    E     0    0
#    F     0    0
#    G     1    0
```

The output seems to be what I need to tally the number of delinquent groups by their status as new or not. Normally, I convert tables to data frames to interact with the data directly. However, in this case, I can't interact with the outputted table object or convert it successfully. I've tried converting it to a data frame via `as.data.frame` and `as.data.frame.matrix` and as a list via `as.list` and `as.data.frame.list`, but the converted output does not seem to be right. Using `as.data.frame.array` is the best I could come up with, but I was expecting a list of two separate data frames, one for each delinquency status. Any suggestions?

```
as.data.frame.array(yo)
#   FALSE.0 TRUE.0 FALSE.1 TRUE.1
# A       0      0       1      0
# B       0      0       0      1
# C       1      0       0      0
# D       0      1       0      0
# E       1      0       0      0
# F       0      1       0      0
# G       0      0       1      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `as.data.frame.table`.

If you want to put everything into one `data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame.table(yo)

   Group   New Delinquent Freq
1      A FALSE          0    0
2      B FALSE          0    0
3      C FALSE          0    1
4      D FALSE          0    0
5      E FALSE          0    1
...
```

If like you said you want a list of `data.frames`:

```
(yolist <- apply(yo, 3, as.data.frame.table))

$`0`
   Group   New Freq
1      A FALSE    0
2      B FALSE    0
3      C FALSE    1
4      D FALSE    0
5      E FALSE    1
...

$`1`
   Group   New Freq
1      A FALSE    1
2      B FALSE    0
3      C FALSE    0
4      D FALSE    0
5      E FALSE    0
...

sapply(yolist, class)
           0            1
"data.frame" "data.frame"
```

This works because your table is 3-dimensional array. The line above constructs a data.frame from a table sliced by appropriate index.

Answer (score 1):

To approach your goal (number of delinquent by new or not) from another tack, you could also use ddply from the plyr package:

```
library(plyr)

yo <- ddply(df, .(Group, New, Delinquent), summarize,
             sum_in_group = length(Delinquent==TRUE)
             )
```

Gives:

```
  Group   New Delinquent sum_in_group
1     A FALSE      FALSE            1
2     A FALSE       TRUE            2
3     B  TRUE      FALSE            1
4     B  TRUE       TRUE            2
5     C FALSE      FALSE            3
6     D  TRUE      FALSE            2
7     E FALSE      FALSE            1
8     F  TRUE      FALSE            1
9     G FALSE       TRUE            1
```

I know that doesn't answer your table question directly, but I find this output easier to deal with myself.

**Edit**

In response to your comment: something like

```
yo <- ddply(df, .(Group, New), summarize,
            Delinquent = max(Delinquent)
);yo

  Group   New Delinquent
1     A FALSE          1
2     B  TRUE          1
3     C FALSE          0
4     D  TRUE          0
5     E FALSE          0
6     F  TRUE          0
7     G FALSE          1
```

Where a 1 in the delinquent column means that the group was delinquent at least once.

Or, maybe you want a column for compliant as well:

With `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Group, New), summarize,
            delinquent = as.numeric(any(Delinquent)), 
            compliant = as.numeric(!any(Delinquent))
)
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(df %>% 
  group_by(Group, New) %>%
  summarize(
    delinquent = as.numeric(any(Delinquent)), 
    compliant = as.numeric(!any(Delinquent))
    )
)
```

Both output:

```
  Group   New delinquent compliant
1     A FALSE          1         0
2     B  TRUE          1         0
3     C FALSE          0         1
4     D  TRUE          0         1
5     E FALSE          0         1
6     F  TRUE          0         1
7     G FALSE          1         0
```

Comment: Huh. I get different output using the `yo` as created in the question itself- am I doing something wrong there? I'm not well-versed at all in `data.table`, so I apologize if I'm not understanding the output properly.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative strategy. As for not getting the same `yo` as in the original post, just to clarify, the `data.table` package was not involved. It used `table` from base R. Either way, your `plyr` output produces what I was looking for, so thank you for that.

Comment: Oh, I was responding to a comment (now deleted) by another user about something I didn't quite understand. Thank you for clarifying though!

Comment: Ah, actually, I misread the output above. The `sum_in_group` output doesn't produce what I was looking for. Across all groups, it should sum up to seven instances, like the `Freq` column in Karolis's answer. It's more of a within-group 'max' than a within-group 'sum' (i.e. I want to know the number of delinquent groups, where any time a group is delinquent, even once, they're considered delinquent, whereas they'd need to be compliant every time to be marked 'not delinquent'). Is there a way to edit your `ddply` solution to obtain the corrected output?

Comment: Gotcha. Edited my answer to see if that's closer, although I will say I do like @Karolis' answer so if it works for you then that's great, I just wanted to present an alternative.